# Changing CSS classes within Ember and SortMixin

Tags: css, ember.js

I have a table which I have applied sorting to but to complete this task I would like the classes to change to show carets going up or down based on the sorting.

As you can see I have used the standard SortableMixin within Ember to get the sorting functionality but I'm having trouble changing the class of the individual element which has been clicked.

```
App.CampaignsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ["id"],
    sortAscending: true,

    actions: {
        sortBy: function(property){
            if (this.get("sortProperties")[0] === property){
                this.toggleProperty("sortAscending");
            } else {
                this.set("sortProperties", [property]);
                this.set("sortAscending", true)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The table I'm I've applied the actions to is below:

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th {{action "sortBy" "name"}}><i {{bind-attr class=":fa sortAscending:fa-caret-up:fa-caret-down"}}></i>Campaign Name</th>
              <th {{action "sortBy" "campaign_code"}}><i {{bind-attr class=":fa sortAscending:fa-caret-up:fa-caret-down"}}></i>Campaign Code</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <td>{{name}}</td>
              <td>{{campaign_code}}</td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I'm using the sortAscending boolean to dictate what CSS class will appear. My problem is if I click the first heading, the classes on the second heading also change.

How do I get the CSS to change only on the heading that I have clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Your `<th>` now has state (whether it's sorted, and whether it's ascending or descending), so you should wrap it up in a component. Something like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {{#sortable-th property='name' action='sortBy'}}
        Campaign Name
      {{/#sortable-th}}
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The component's template

```
// templates/components/sortable-th.js
<th>
  <i {{bind-attr class=":fa sortAscending:fa-caret-up:fa-caret-down"}}></i>
  {{yield}}
</th>
```

and code

```
// components/sortable-th.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  sortAscending: true,

  click: function() {
    this.toggleProperty('sortAscending');
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('property'), this.get('sortAscending'));
  }
}
```

That's just a rough outline, try the implementation yourself. But that's how I would start thinking about it.